# Is there a way for pandas cumsum() to handle NaN as zero?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with some NaN values in a column that I'm trying to compute the cumulative sum for. Rather than pre-filling the NaN with 0, is there a way for cumsum to just ignore NaN?

Comment: No, you have to `fillna(0)` if you want to fill the NaNs with the cumulated sums. If you want to have NaNs, leave the default `skipna=True`.

Comment: @mozway I'm confused what the `skipna` does. it apparently excludes nan values, but when I turn it on and off, I get the same results even though there's nan values in my column?

Comment: It sets NaNs to all values after a NaN, see the [example in the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), but it's not what you need.

Comment: In what way do you want to ignore the `NaN` values? Some sample data would help explain the question

Answer (score 0):

```
def notnull_index(col: str) -> list:
    '''
    Returns list of indices where column value is not NaN
    '''
    return list(df[df[col].notnull()==True].index)

def cumsum(col: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    '''
    Returns the cumsum of the column for non-NaN values
    '''
    # List of indices where the rows are not null
    idx = notnull_index(col)
    # Filters DataFrame on non-null rows
    df_notnull = df[df.index.isin(idx)]
    # Computes the cumulative sum of the column
    result = reduce(lambda x, y: x + [x[-1]+y] if x else [y], df_notnull[col], [])
    # Creates a new column filled with NaN values
    df[f'cumsum_{col}'] = np.nan
    # Fill the cumsum column with the cumsum values at the right indices
    df.loc[df.index.isin(idx), f'cumsum_{col}'] = result
    # Ffill the missing values 
    df[f'cumsum_{col}'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    return df
```

This should work, assuming that your DataFrame is called df.
Still fillna(0) is much better ;)

Comment: it is a bit overcomplicated. the question was clear if there is another way but I think using fillna(0) is better